# コードブロック内のテキストをコピーする機能の要望

Tags: 機能の要求

### 動機

質問に書かれた現象の再現確認を行なうため、コードをコピーする必要がありました。そこで私は 「Shift + クリック」による範囲選択を用いてコードのコピーを行ないました。

しかし、そのコードは長く、コードの起点から終点までをスクロールすることに手間がかかりました。また、始端もしくは終端の文字を選択し損ねてしまうこともありました。

---

### 機能導入の利点

機能を導入することによる主な利点は、以下のとおりです。また、機能を導入することによる欠点は今のところ、考えついていません。

- デバイスによらず共通した操作でコードのコピーが行なえる。
- コードの選択に手間がかからない。
- コードの選択時に選択漏れが発生することを考慮しなくて良い。

---

### 他 Q&A サイトでの実装状況

他 Q&A サイトでの実装状況を調べたところ、以下のようになっているようです。実装しているサイトが意外と少ないため、何か致命的な欠点があるのかと思いましたが、これは単にコードブロックの挿入に対応している Q&A サイトが少ないためではないかと思います。

#### 実装済み

- [teratail【テラテイル】｜ITエンジニア特化型Q&Aサイト](https://teratail.com/)

#### 未実装

- [Quora - 知識を共有し合い、世界を知ろう](https://jp.quora.com/)
- [ITエンジニア向け質問・回答コミュニティ - QA@IT](https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/)
- [Yahoo!知恵袋](https://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/)
- [質問・疑問に答えるQ&AサイトOKWAVE](https://okwave.jp/)
- [人力検索はてな](http://q.hatena.ne.jp/)

---

### 関連投稿

- [Shortcut or button for copying posted code from Stack Overflow - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32625)
- [Select All / Copy All Button for Code - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251883)
- [Copy button on code blocks - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375276)

Comment: Meta Stack Exchange に同様の機能要求があるのを見つけました: [Shortcut or button for copying posted code from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32625/341401)

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん> ありがとうございます。当該ページを含めたリンクを、関連投稿として質問文に追記しました。

Answer (score 3):

代替案として [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/61866) というUserscriptに「コードブロックのコピー」機能が含まれています。

事前にブラウザへGreasemonkeyやTampermonkey、Violentmonkeyなどの拡張機能をインストールしておき、上記のスクリプトをインストールします。初回のアクセストークン設定などが終わればSEネットワークのサイトを開いた際にさまざまな機能が追加、改善されるようになります。

Userscriptをインストールした状態でコードブロック上にマウスを移動すると右上端にアイコンが表示されるので、そのままクリックするとクリップボードにコピーされます。